# EF 0..1 to 0..1 relationship without shared primary key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entities which I would like to configure an optional 1-1 relationship (i.e. 0..1 to 0..1).  I would like to do this using a key only on one entity, while having navigation properties in both directions.

Consider the following simplified example to illustrate:

```
public class Person 
{ 
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int? TicketId { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket 
{
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

There are a number of People, and a number of Tickets.  A person can possess at most one ticket.  There are people with no ticket, and unclaimed tickets.

I thought the following might work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Ticket)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Person);
```

But this creates an additional ID on the Ticket table.

I know this is possible using two optional relationships, but this is not an ideal solution as it requires two calls to SaveChanges, and does not guarantee referential integrity (e.g. Person1 could own Ticket1, but Ticket1 could point to Person2).

Similar questions have usually focussed on a 1-0..1 relationship where the principal entity's primary key can be used on the dependent - this is not suitable either.

I am using EF6 Code-First.

Comment: Many to many join table but each foreign key column on the join table also has its own unique index?

Comment: EF doesn't handle this kind of association well